# how to not allow other user to copy my script in remote server

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

experts, i am using a Linux server where the same username and password are used by other persons to login and perform their work. Some time they delete and misplace my scripts from that server.So in order to overcome this problem i want to know are there any procedure so that other users of same id cannot see and access my scripts.I hope experts will help me in this regard.

```
i am using `ssh` command to login

i am also trying to hide the script but not successfully done it.
```

Comment: If you only have one user then it is not possible to completely stop others from accessing/deleting any of the files owned by that user. You can change the permissions to make the file inaccessible but anyone else logged in as the same user can change the permissions back again. In short, your server is poorly set up if you have this requirement and only have the one user.

Comment: if it is so are there any way to run the script from local machine without copying to remote machine

Comment: Of course you can just run the script on the local machine. But that's not the same as running the script on the remote machine. I guess what you are really asking is whether you can run the script on the remote machine without copying the file across. The answer is no you cannot. The script must somehow get to the remote machine for it to run there. One workaround could be for you to write a helper script that copies your script to the remote machine, runs it and then finally deletes it when it finishes running. Or you can mount your local machine onto the remote machine if you know how.

Answer (score 0):

Unix systems are not designed to protect against unwanted or malicious accesses from the same user.  If all of the people on the machine are using the same user account, then to a Linux or Unix system, they are the same user, and each and every human has the same privileges to act on that file.

If you want to have different access control permissions for different humans, then they need to have different accounts.  This is the basis of security permissions for Unix systems.  This is also why many daemons run as their own unprivileged user: so that if one process gets compromised, it is unable to negatively affect other things on the system.